# Access to the path denied. C# unable to create

Tags: c#

I am working on a PGP decryption code...here all access to the directory is granted in security tab and path exists but at the end of decryption where the decrypted file is created and to be placed this error occurs

code

```
--- path declaration----
string outputPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutPutPath"];

--- in app config
<add key="OutPutPath" value="D:\Decryption\Output"/>

--- checking path is existing or not
(here it shows that the path exists)

if (!Directory.Exists(outputPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);
                }

decryption

Crypto.Decrypt(item, privateKeyPath, DecipherTextPhrase.Trim(), outputPath);
```

```
 public static void  Decrypt(Stream inputStream, Stream privateKeyStream, string passPhrase, string outputFile)
        {
            try
            {
                PgpObjectFactory pgpF = null;
                PgpEncryptedDataList enc = null;
                PgpObject o = null;
                PgpPrivateKey sKey = null;
                PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
                PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec = null;

                pgpF = new PgpObjectFactory(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream));
                // find secret key 
                pgpSec = new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(privateKeyStream));

                if (pgpF != null)
                    o = pgpF.NextPgpObject();

                // the first object might be a PGP marker packet. 
                if (o is PgpEncryptedDataList)
                    enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)o;
                else
                    enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgpF.NextPgpObject();

                // decrypt 
                foreach (PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pked in enc.GetEncryptedDataObjects())
                {
                    sKey = FindSecretKey(pgpSec, pked.KeyId, passPhrase.ToCharArray());

                    if (sKey != null)
                    {
                        pbe = pked;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (sKey == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Secret key for message not found.");

                PgpObjectFactory plainFact = null;

                using (Stream clear = pbe.GetDataStream(sKey))
                {
                    plainFact = new PgpObjectFactory(clear);
                }

                PgpObject message = plainFact.NextPgpObject();

                if (message is PgpCompressedData)
                {
                    PgpCompressedData cData = (PgpCompressedData)message;
                    PgpObjectFactory of = null;

                    using (Stream compDataIn = cData.GetDataStream())
                    {
                        of = new PgpObjectFactory(compDataIn);
                    }

                    message = of.NextPgpObject();
                    if (message is PgpOnePassSignatureList)
                    {
                        message = of.NextPgpObject();
                        PgpLiteralData Ld = null;
                        Ld = (PgpLiteralData)message;
                        
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ld.FileName))
                            outputFile = outputFile + (Ld.FileName.EndsWith(".txt")? Ld.FileName:Ld.FileName+".txt");
                        else
                            outputFile = outputFile + "test" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".txt";
                        using (Stream output = File.Create(outputFile))
                        {
                            Stream unc = Ld.GetInputStream();
                            Streams.PipeAll(unc, output);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PgpLiteralData Ld = null;
                        Ld = (PgpLiteralData)message;
                        using (Stream output = File.Create(outputFile)) ----**error occurs here**
                        {
                            Stream unc = Ld.GetInputStream();
                            Streams.PipeAll(unc, output);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: And the error says that access is denied? Maybe you need to be administrator or something?

Comment: What is the output filename?  Looking at the code it seems you would only get the access error if you cannot read the file.  Make sure you can write to the file.  VS you do not run As Admin unless you right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Use the debugger to see why you should be using Path.Combine()